# nginx: variable expansion inside split_clients not working?

Tags: nginx

i have the following config:

```
map $host $variant_a {
  default 'a';
}
map $host $variant_b {
  default 'b';
}
map $host $variant_c {
  default 'c';
}
map $host $variant_d {
  default 'd';
}
map $host $variant_default {
  default 'default';
}
# a/b testing
split_clients "abtest${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}${date_gmt}" $variant_chosen {
    20%     $variant_a;
    20%     $variant_b;
    20%     $variant_c;
    20%     $variant_d;
    20%     $variant_default;
}

server {
    # defaults test independent
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /home/vagrant/www;
    index index.html;
    error_page 404 = 404.html;
    error_page 403 = 404.html;

    location / {
        echo a=$variant_a,variant_chosen=$variant_chosen
    }

}
```

when i execute a query against the server:

```
curl -i http://192.168.33.10/
```

i can see that the variables inside the `'split_clients'` get never expanded.

sample output:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/www$ curl -i http://192.168.33.10/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 15:46:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

a=a,variant_chosen=$variant_default
```

anybody any idea why the variables are not expanded?

any help highly appreciated

cheers
marcel

Comment: Documentation does not say you could use variables in `split_clients`, so it's just plain strings.

Comment: And what you want to do really?

Comment: i found another way to achive the thing i want. i still want to know why the variables aren't expanded. any idea?

Comment: Why should they? There are lot of places where nginx intentionally or historically doesn't expect variables and doesn't expand them. Probably `split_clients` is one of these places. You could provide a patch to support variables, but there are little need for them here.

Comment: ok. that could be an answer. is there a documentation explaining where variables will be expanded and not? cheers.

Comment: Well, nginx's documentations is not ideal but usually there is mention of variables if they are allowed. Like «A value can contain variables.» in http://nginx.org/r/add_header

Comment: how can i close the question?